# Timer Causes Program to Get Stuck (Windows Forms), Throwing "The Debugger is not Properly Installed" Error

Tags: c#, timer, windows-forms-designer

Hope everyone is well.

I am trying to create a live dashboard, which is connected to an MySQL Database. The SQL Database gets updated from an external command with "INSERT" commands, to log the new sensor readings.

I have 6 labels to display the live sensor readings. My aim is to update the values displayed in every 1 second. Because of that I wanted to use timer configuration which I am not familiar with. I looked up the sources and this site, to create some code to achieve that purpose, however, I was not successful at it.

Here is some part of my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace LVAD_Form
{
    public partial class Veri_Ekrani : Form
    {
        public Veri_Ekrani()
        {
            InitializeComponent();   
        }

        private void Veri_Ekrani_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = (3 * 1000); // 10 secs
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            timer.Start();

        }

        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String username = "bla";
            String password = "blabla";

            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("host=blabla;username=" + username + ";password=" + password + ";");

            String strSQL = "SELECT * FROM haberlesme_verisi WHERE sayici=(SELECT MAX(sayici) FROM haberlesme_verisi);";

            var cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strSQL, connection);

            connection.Open();

            var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                dr.Read();// Get first record.
                // indices 0 and 1 are for timestamp and counter.
                labelVoltaj.Text = dr.GetString(4);
                labelAkim.Text = dr.GetString(5);
                labelDevir.Text = dr.GetString(6);

                labelBasinc.Text = dr.GetString(2);
                labelAkis.Text = dr.GetString(3);
            }
            else
            {
                labelVoltaj.Text = "Veri Alınamadı";
                labelAkim.Text = "Veri Alınamadı";
                labelDevir.Text = "Veri Alınamadı";

                labelBasinc.Text = "Veri Alınamadı";
                labelAkis.Text = "Veri Alınamadı";
            }
            dr.Close();// Close reader.
            connection.Close();// Close connection.
        }

        private void msg_Box_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void chart2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void chart2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void chart1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

When I run the script/form, the program gets stuck after approximately 3 second passes. Then I receive the error "The Debugger is not properly installed. Run setup to install or repair the debugger". At this point, Process Memory chart is also gets stuck around 87 percent.

I also noticed that, when I close the error message, I see that my script is always at the statement:

```
var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I am sorry if the code is poorly structured. I have an (not school related) assignment whose due date is very soon and this is my first time using C#, and Windows Form Designer. I did not have much time the grasp the basics - which is definitely not a good approach but the time is very important for me right now.

Comment: Inside an event handler, you have `Timer timer = new Timer();` and a bunch of configuration of that timer. When the handler routine ended, `timer` goes out of scope and becomes eligible for garbage collection. At that point, I don't know what happens. Makebthe timer a member of your form's class (you can drag a Timer from the toolbox to your form to do this if you'd like)

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much!